# can a VM on-premises use Azure DNS when connected to Azure through an S2S connection?

Tags: azure, networking, dns, azure-dns

Would a VM on-premises connected to Azure through an S2S VPN tunnel be able to query Azure DNS (168.63.129.16) for Azure private zones, or would a custom DNS be required to forward the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need a custom DNS proxy server to forward queries to Azure for DNS resolution.

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

Comment: Hi Nancy, after researching I found that indeed that is the way to go. I have to set a DNS server in Azure and then I can make it forward the resolution queries to Azure DNS, thanks!